# Traceroute returning different results on the same network

Tags: dns, traceroute

I ran an `mtr` on my Ubuntu machine, and at roughly the same time on a Kali vm. I tested this on my home network with different network adapters for each OS; However the results i get differ sometimes even drastically so.

The only thing i have changed about the Ubuntu device is the DNS service. It uses `dnsmasq` + `dnscrypt-proxy` while the Kali vm uses default configuration + google DNS.

Here are `mtr` and `nslookup` results for google.com(Don't mind the timestamps, the OS times are not synced):

- Kali vm:

```
root@kali:~# mtr -rw google.com
Start: 2019-10-07T11:44:05-0400
HOST: kali           Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- _gateway        0.0%    10    3.3 592.7   2.2 1129. 442.8
  2.|-- 172.16.64.134   0.0%    10   13.6 544.2   8.4 1068. 426.7
  3.|-- 172.16.64.133  10.0%    10  1455. 693.7  61.6 1455. 460.9
  4.|-- 10.201.177.241 10.0%    10  1364. 609.2   9.8 1364. 455.5
  5.|-- 10.202.4.83    40.0%    10  666.9 477.6  39.2 966.4 409.2
  6.|-- 213.202.4.172  20.0%    10  605.5 723.2 226.2 1179. 356.6
  7.|-- 213.202.4.185  10.0%    10  925.2 654.7 104.7 1168. 375.1
  8.|-- ???            100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  9.|-- 172.253.51.130 10.0%    10  738.7 495.5  40.9 984.6 349.2
 10.|-- 216.239.51.113 10.0%    10  647.5 675.8 194.4 1164. 362.4
 11.|-- google.com     30.0%    10  1106. 665.9 105.1 1106. 370.0

root@kali:~# nslookup google.com
;; Got recursion not available from fe80::1%3, trying next server
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.18.142
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4018:803::200e
```

- Ubuntu:

```
ali@Linuxity:~$ mtr -rw google.com
Start: 2019-10-07T19:14:07+0330
HOST: Linuxity                  Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- _gateway                   0.0%    10    4.1   3.0   2.4   4.4   0.7
  2.|-- 172.16.64.134              0.0%    10    7.9  11.9   7.6  28.1   6.0
  3.|-- 172.16.64.133              0.0%    10   34.7  53.5   6.9 276.4  84.9
  4.|-- 10.201.177.241             0.0%    10    8.1  46.5   7.9 232.7  75.8
  5.|-- 10.202.4.83                0.0%    10   50.0  69.1  38.9 193.6  46.7
  6.|-- 213.202.4.172             10.0%    10   80.1  89.3  71.3 152.6  25.2
  7.|-- 213.202.4.185              0.0%    10   47.2  47.0  46.5  49.6   0.9
  8.|-- ???                       100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  9.|-- 172.253.51.132             0.0%    10   43.0  43.1  42.5  44.1   0.5
 10.|-- 108.170.240.56             0.0%    10   83.6  90.2  74.0 169.4  28.1
 11.|-- 209.85.240.12              0.0%    10   44.0  56.9  43.2 141.4  30.2
 12.|-- 172.253.51.215             0.0%    10  163.0 186.9 162.2 405.9  76.9
 13.|-- 216.239.35.209             0.0%    10  164.8 204.8 163.7 542.0 118.7
 14.|-- 172.253.70.208             0.0%    10  236.9 294.5 236.9 590.0 117.4
 15.|-- 216.239.57.136             0.0%    10  254.6 303.9 254.6 586.2 110.3
 16.|-- 209.85.143.103             0.0%    10  265.6 320.6 263.7 641.7 125.0
 17.|-- 108.170.233.245            0.0%    10  331.6 386.0 324.6 668.8 108.9
 18.|-- 108.170.236.119            0.0%    10  422.9 453.5 410.5 630.0  70.5
 19.|-- 216.239.63.163             0.0%    10  422.6 445.1 410.2 586.4  53.6
 20.|-- 209.85.244.63              0.0%    10  382.9 405.5 382.3 542.7  52.3
 21.|-- 108.170.242.161            0.0%    10  383.2 396.6 382.2 499.0  36.6
 22.|-- 74.125.251.235            30.0%    10  383.2 385.6 383.2 394.1   3.8
 23.|-- nrt20s08-in-f14.1e100.net  0.0%    10  380.6 384.0 379.9 414.4  10.7

ali@Linuxity:~$ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.31.142
Name:   google.com
Address: 2404:6800:4004:808::200e
```

---

It's like this for most websites, but for some It's even worse.
My ISP blocks specific websites, so i expect to see no output when i do a traceroute on them, but these are `traceroute` results for facebook.com (a blocked website):

- Kali vm (gives out my expected result):

```
root@kali:~# traceroute facebook.com
traceroute to facebook.com (10.10.34.35), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  16.924 ms  16.837 ms  16.796 ms
 2  172.16.64.134 (172.16.64.134)  17.321 ms  19.512 ms  21.178 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

- Ubuntu:

```
ali@Linuxity:~$ traceroute facebook.com
traceroute to facebook.com (31.13.64.35), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  2.931 ms  3.275 ms  3.660 ms
 2  172.16.64.134 (172.16.64.134)  16.868 ms  17.432 ms  18.203 ms
 3  172.16.64.133 (172.16.64.133)  19.231 ms  20.119 ms  22.204 ms
 4  78.38.119.182 (78.38.119.182)  22.480 ms 10.201.177.241 (10.201.177.241)  24.190 ms 78.38.119.182 (78.38.119.182)  24.440 ms
 5  10.202.4.83 (10.202.4.83)  77.326 ms 10.202.4.81 (10.202.4.81)  31.733 ms 10.202.4.83 (10.202.4.83)  77.072 ms
 6  10.21.0.11 (10.21.0.11)  35.136 ms ae9.pr01.fra4.tfbnw.net (103.4.96.16)  106.308 ms  105.593 ms
 7  ae9.pr01.fra4.tfbnw.net (103.4.96.16)  105.976 ms * *
 8  ae122.ar02.fra2.tfbnw.net (157.240.32.104)  96.944 ms ae112.ar01.fra2.tfbnw.net (31.13.26.14)  94.836 ms *
 9  ae4.bb02.fra5.tfbnw.net (31.13.26.8)  96.613 ms ae122.ar01.fra2.tfbnw.net (173.252.64.158)  139.115 ms ae122.ar02.fra2.tfbnw.net (157.240.32.104)  108.266 ms
10  ae17.bb01.fra2.tfbnw.net (157.240.47.106)  136.744 ms ae3.bb02.fra2.tfbnw.net (31.13.27.202)  98.110 ms  98.214 ms
11  ae0.ar01.ams2.tfbnw.net (157.240.35.39)  157.430 ms ae2.bb02.ams2.tfbnw.net (74.119.78.92)  156.951 ms ae8.bb02.ams3.tfbnw.net (31.13.27.65)  159.645 ms
12  po211.asw02.ams2.tfbnw.net (157.240.34.203)  197.090 ms ae2.bb02.ams2.tfbnw.net (74.119.78.92)  157.658 ms ae0.ar01.ams2.tfbnw.net (157.240.35.39)  160.155 ms
13  po211.asw02.ams2.tfbnw.net (157.240.34.203)  197.532 ms ae5.bb01.ams3.tfbnw.net (31.13.27.45)  166.561 ms ae1.ar01.ams3.tfbnw.net (157.240.34.173)  189.756 ms
14  po225.psw02.ams2.tfbnw.net (157.240.47.45)  151.310 ms po211.psw04.ams2.tfbnw.net (74.119.78.13)  190.452 ms po241.psw01.ams2.tfbnw.net (157.240.35.179)  150.859 ms
15  173.252.67.157 (173.252.67.157)  150.854 ms 173.252.67.167 (173.252.67.167)  177.751 ms po241.asw02.ams3.tfbnw.net (157.240.34.225)  153.693 ms
16  edge-star-mini-shv-01-amt2.facebook.com (31.13.64.35)  154.070 ms  154.706 ms 157.240.38.253 (157.240.38.253)  146.896 ms
```

What is causing this? I've searched everywhere with no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: After testing this on Termux from my phone, on mobile data as well as our home wifi, the results are same as the Kali vm results. This means whatever's causing this is from the OS itself.

---

### Edit

Sorry for the late reply, i got busy with my studies.
As suggested, i used traceroute on IP's instead and here are the results for facebook.com, IP's were taken from `nslookup`. Ubuntu returned `157.240.201.35` and Kali `10.10.34.35`. Here i did a traceroute to both of these IP's from each device:

- Ubuntu:

```
ali@Linuxity:~$ mtr -rw 157.240.201.35
Start: 2019-10-17T13:55:24+0330
HOST: Linuxity                                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- _gateway                                 0.0%    10    2.6   2.8   2.5   4.2   0.5
  2.|-- 172.16.64.134                            0.0%    10   11.8   8.8   7.8  11.8   1.3
  3.|-- 172.16.64.133                            0.0%    10    7.7   8.1   7.4   9.3   0.6
  4.|-- 78.38.119.182                            0.0%    10    8.6   8.0   7.5   8.6   0.4
  5.|-- 10.202.4.81                              0.0%    10   10.3  10.2   9.2  11.8   0.9
  6.|-- 10.21.0.11                               0.0%    10   10.1   9.6   8.4  10.8   0.8
  7.|-- ae9.pr01.fra4.tfbnw.net                  0.0%    10   91.5  85.6  82.8  91.5   3.2
  8.|-- ???                                     100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  9.|-- ae112.ar02.fra2.tfbnw.net                0.0%    10   84.6  86.7  83.2  98.5   4.8
 10.|-- ae33.bb01.fra2.tfbnw.net                 0.0%    10  113.0  91.4  85.1 113.0  10.2
 11.|-- ae12.bb02.ams2.tfbnw.net                 0.0%    10   91.7  92.7  91.5  95.1   1.4
 12.|-- ae1.ar01.ams2.tfbnw.net                  0.0%    10   94.1  98.5  92.2 118.6   8.6
 13.|-- po211.asw02.ams2.tfbnw.net               0.0%    10   91.6  92.5  91.6  94.3   0.9
 14.|-- po224.psw03.ams4.tfbnw.net               0.0%    10   90.2  90.7  89.9  92.5   0.7
 15.|-- 173.252.67.107                           0.0%    10   92.3  95.1  91.6 121.5   9.3
 16.|-- edge-star-mini-shv-01-ams4.facebook.com  0.0%    10   89.3  90.3  88.9  93.6   1.5
ali@Linuxity:~$ mtr -rw 10.10.34.35
Start: 2019-10-17T14:00:50+0330
HOST: Linuxity      Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- _gateway       0.0%    10    2.5   8.1   2.4  58.6  17.7
  2.|-- 172.16.64.134  0.0%    10    7.9   9.4   7.7  14.6   2.4
  3.|-- ???           100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

- Kali vm:

```
root@kali:~# mtr -rw 157.240.201.35
Start: 2019-10-17T06:31:46-0400
HOST: kali                                    Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- _gateway                                 0.0%    10    2.2   2.8   2.2   3.9   0.5
  2.|-- 172.16.64.134                            0.0%    10    8.1  17.5   8.1  28.8   7.2
  3.|-- 172.16.64.133                            0.0%    10    7.1   8.1   7.1   9.6   0.8
  4.|-- 78.38.119.182                            0.0%    10    8.4   8.1   6.9   8.9   0.6
  5.|-- 10.202.4.81                              0.0%    10    9.9  10.4   8.4  13.4   1.5
  6.|-- 10.21.0.11                               0.0%    10   11.4  10.3   8.7  12.1   1.1
  7.|-- ae9.pr01.fra4.tfbnw.net                  0.0%    10   91.4  85.5  83.3  91.4   2.3
  8.|-- ???                                     100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  9.|-- ae112.ar02.fra2.tfbnw.net                0.0%    10   86.5  90.5  83.3 109.5   8.7
 10.|-- ae33.bb01.fra2.tfbnw.net                 0.0%    10   87.8  86.8  85.0  89.6   1.4
 11.|-- ae12.bb02.ams2.tfbnw.net                 0.0%    10   97.0  92.7  90.3  97.0   2.0
 12.|-- ae1.ar01.ams2.tfbnw.net                  0.0%    10   93.9  95.2  92.4 102.7   3.6
 13.|-- po211.asw02.ams2.tfbnw.net               0.0%    10   92.5  92.1  91.1  92.6   0.5
 14.|-- po224.psw03.ams4.tfbnw.net               0.0%    10   90.2  90.3  89.0  91.6   0.7
 15.|-- 173.252.67.107                           0.0%    10   92.4  92.1  90.4  94.4   1.1
 16.|-- edge-star-mini-shv-01-ams4.facebook.com  0.0%    10   89.7  90.1  88.8  91.5   0.8
root@kali:~# mtr -rw 10.10.34.35
Start: 2019-10-17T06:32:21-0400
HOST: kali          Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- _gateway       0.0%    10    2.4   2.7   2.2   3.0   0.3
  2.|-- 172.16.64.134  0.0%    10    8.2  14.2   8.0  53.1  13.8
  3.|-- ???           100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

As apparent the results are identical. I tried it with other websites to but even then the first few results seemed to make much more sense.

I tried the same inputs with a VPN service enabled. Tracerouting the 'private' `10.10.34.35` address just caused an infinite loop in `_gateway` which actually confirms your suggestions, and doing so for facebook.com now showed no sign of these private addresses either.

The default method was UDP here, but using TCP gave very similar results.

Another interesting thing that happened was that after another traceroute on the previous IP `31.13.64.35`, the results were now different, indicating it was probably a newer address and it recently got blocked by my ISP.

---

This all shows me how little you can trust your ISP with any unencrypted DNS requests and how they can be easily manipulated...
Anyway, thank you all for the inputs! I wish i could give you all the bounty but I'll just give it to `antichris` as his answer gave a really good summary and understanding of the subject.

Comment: The same name can resolve to different ip address depending on the name server  (or ISP/location) used, or two queries to the same name server can give different result (or the result can have multiple addresses). Also, traceroute to the same IP address can be different between two retries, even if only couple of seconds apart (although you will not see this too often)

Comment: @DusanBajic Well the results are persistent so it must be the name server. If so why are the first few IP's in the traceroute  identical? I mean at what point does the name server change the route?

Comment: You should separately analyze name resolving process, which just translate names to ip addresses (and notice the differences thare), and then analyze tracerouting to ip addresses, not names; I think that approach will give you more insight.

Comment: I would always traceroute for IP, not the DNS. There's no point in comparing two machines when you clearly attempt to reach different servers. Moreover, your Kali trace for facebook.com shows invalid IP address - 10.0.0.0/8 is reserved for private use, it's not possible that a public server has an IP from this range. It's possible however that a DNS is spoofed to lead you into an invalid IP and thus block the site. Try to trace route to 31.13.64.35 from kali as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Will try them as soon as i can and I'll post the results here.

Comment: Could you check whether you're performing an ICMP or a UDP traceroute in both cases? Different traceroute implementations can have different defaults. Try to explicitly set the protocol using `traceroute -I` or `traceroute -U`, see if this affects the results. Also check packet sizes and try to set them manually to a consistent value.

Comment: @raspy `172.16/12` is also a private prefix. And my current ISP also is dumb enough to use `10/8` instead of `100.64/10` for addressing their infrastructure (routers, gateways, etc.), which has already been causing issues for users on my `192.168/24` LAN (had to set a rule on FW to reject all outgoing `10/8` traffic).

Comment: @Malt In the case of facebook.com omantel gives private IP address 10.10.34.35 which is routed to black hole. Results will be same for any protocol and any packet size.

Comment: Thank you all with your inputs! check the last part of the post for answers. I'll be closing this question now as I'm satisfied with the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Routing

What you're seeing is your trace bouncing around within the infrastructure of your ISP for the first few hops (`172.16.0.0/12` and `10.0.0.0/8` are private network address blocks):

```
...
  2.|-- 172.16.64.134
  3.|-- 172.16.64.133
  4.|-- 10.201.177.241
  5.|-- 10.202.4.83
...
```

and after that, within the target infrastructures (both Google and Facebook operate vast multihost networks):

- `172.253.0.0/16` is Google LLC,
- `103.4.96.0/22` is Facebook Singapore Pte Ltd.

Also, notice the striking similarity between
the private `10.202.4.83` and the two OmanMobile Telecommunication company addresses in the `213.202.0.0/20` network right after that:

```
...
  5.|-- 10.202.4.83
  6.|-- 213.202.4.172
  7.|-- 213.202.4.185
...
```

I believe they are not only correlated, but map directly.

The different hosts in hops after leaving your ISP's network is [dynamic routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_routing) at work.

## DNS Spoofing

As for why does `traceroute` to facebook.com fizzle out after `172.16.64.134` — is plain and simple: your ISP intercepts your attempts to look up DNS on Google's `8.8.8.8` service and spoofs replies for facebook.com to resolve to  `10.10.34.35`, which is a private address in your ISP's infrastructure (and may even not be an actual connected host). When you request IP address for the same domain name over DNSCrypt, your ISP can't listen in and spoof responses and you get a valid response: `31.13.64.35` (Facebook Ireland Ltd, `31.13.64.0/18`).

In conclusion, this all makes a convincing case for using tools like DNS over TLS, DNS over HTTPS and DNSCrypt — these all prevent malicious actors from intercepting and redirecting your traffic to their infrastructure.

And remember: `whois` is your friend!

Comment: This clears things up and is very straight to the point. Just one more question: Are there any more of these private addresses i should look out for? Thanks!

Comment: @Xosrov [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network "Private network - Wikipedia") gives a fair overview, as does [the relevant subsection](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPReservedPrivateandLoopbackAddresses-3.htm "The TCP/IP Guide - IP Reserved, Loopback and Private Addresses") of [The TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/index.htm "The TCP/IP Guide") (which is a recommended reading in its entirety if you're into networking). And then there's the [RFC1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918#section-3 "RFC 1918 - Address Allocation for Private Internets") of course.